# Delete lines of tab separated file with date older than 21 days - Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have multiple .csv files looking something like this which is tab-separated:

```
Call ID Latitude    Longitude   Date and Time   wasd
wasd    12.1241234  12.1243 2021-12-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
wasd    12.1241234  12.1243 2021-12-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
wasd    12.1241234  12.1243 2022-1-15 07:45:13.123  wasd
wasd    12.1241234  12.1243 2022-2-15 07:45:13.123  wasd
wasd    12.1241234  12.1243 2022-2-15 07:45:13.123  wasd
```

Using powershell I need to delete all the lines of the file with a date older than 21 days.
unfortunately im limited to use Powershell only. Any Powershell experts out there?

Comment: use `Import-Csv` to bring in the data. convert the datetime _strings_ into datetime _objects_. subtract the old time from $Now, get the `.TotalDays`, and compare that to your `$MaxDaysOld`. delete the lines that fail that test. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you need to only keep the rows that have a 'Date and Time' newer or equal than 21 days ago
To do that, use a `Where-Object` clause to filter on only the rows you want to keep:

```
# get the reference date set to midnight
$threeWeeksAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-21).Date
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Blah.tsv' -Delimiter "`t" | 
# pass rows newer or equal than 21 days ago
Where-Object { [datetime]$_.'Date and Time' -ge $threeWeeksAgo } | 
# write out to (new) file
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\CleanedUpBlah.tsv' -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

- On my Dutch machine, `[datetime]$_.'Date and Time'` parses the dates correctly, but depending on your system's locale (date & time culture settings) you may need to use
  `[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Date and Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff', $null)`
- Since your CSV file is TAB delimited, I'm using extension `.tsv` (Tab Separated Values) but the code will accept any extension you have given it.

Result on screen using your example:

```
Call ID Latitude   Longitude Date and Time          wasd
------- --------   --------- -------------          ----
wasd    12.1241234 12.1243   2022-2-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
wasd    12.1241234 12.1243   2022-2-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
```

---

If, as you have commented, you would also like have a csv containing the rows that were removed with the above code, you could do this:

```
# get the reference date set to midnight
$threeWeeksAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-21).Date
$fileToCleanUp = 'D:\Test\Blah.tsv'
Import-Csv -Path $fileToCleanUp -Delimiter "`t" | 
# pass rows older than 21 days ago
Where-Object { [datetime]$_.'Date and Time' -lt $threeWeeksAgo } |
# add a property with the file name where this line is removed 
Select-Object @{Name = 'DeletedFrom'; Expression = {$fileToCleanUp}}, * |
# write out to (new) file
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\RemovedFromBlah.tsv' -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen using your example:

```
DeletedFrom      Call ID Latitude   Longitude Date and Time           wasd
-----------      ------- --------   --------- -------------           ----
D:\Test\Blah.tsv wasd    12.1241234 12.1243   2021-12-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
D:\Test\Blah.tsv wasd    12.1241234 12.1243   2021-12-15 07:45:13.123 wasd
D:\Test\Blah.tsv wasd    12.1241234 12.1243   2022-1-15 07:45:13.123  wasd
```

Comment: Great answere, this will do the trick! If I wish to print out the filename and then delete it if this criteria comes true:

'''
Where-Object { [datetime]$_.'Date and Time' -lt $threeWeeksAgo }
'''
Would it be any simple adjustments to the above script?

Comment: @SHR Please see my edit. This will create a file with rows older than 3 weeks ago including the file name. Is that what you wanted?